# Is there any significance to the snowman's head in the Tundra Express?

Tags: borderlands-2

Last night while I was completing one of Tiny Tina's side missions in the Tundra Express I saw that the bandit house on the path from the entrance had a snowman's head (complete with carrot nose, and I think a top hat) sitting on the ground next to the house's door.

At the time I thought it was odd that I hadn't noticed it before but just chalked it up to not paying attention.  But today, after going back to the area I see that it isn't there.

Does anyone know why it showed up?  Does it have any meaning?

Comment: Not sure about significance, but from my experience the head can be destroyed by weapons/punches. Maybe that's what happened?

Comment: Right after I posted this I went back to the fast travel station and saw there was a whole snowman there....of course the first thing I did was blow its head off :D  But that didn't cause it show back up at the bandit house.  For now I'll just chalk it up to a random event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a random object that will spawn either a weapon or ammos when shot. But if you're lucky, you can get the Flynt's Tinderbox from this snowman. Beside that, nothing else interesting about it.

Comment: I've started the game a few times and I seem to be guaranteed a Tinderbox from this head if you're on the mission where you first get to Tundra Express and need to light some varkids on fire.

Comment: It appears you need to be at the **START** of the mission "A Train To Catch". It's to help set the varkids on fire.